# share database between same app working on different physical devices in android

Tags: android, database

Guys i have a database in my app and wish to share that with the app working on some other device ! 
Have been trying since 8 hours! Kindly provide me with some code or a working example. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you expand your requirements? Are you happy to transfer the db once only to the other device? Or do you want it fully shared where each can update the db and expect the other to see the changes? Is the other device always on a local network (bonjour/avahi) or can it be anywhere? Should the db in fact live on a server somewhere? Is it available when the first device is unavailable?

Comment: alright i want to fully share the dB whenever they(any number of users) run the application, i expect them to see the changes. No, the other device is not required to be always available. Anyone who uses the app will modify the dB and hence changes must be reflected to all.

Comment: **"Or it can be like creating a database on every physical device and whenever changes are made to the database it sync with other dB"**

Comment: As Raghu points out, you can use Bluetooth or NFC, but you could also use zeroconf over local WiFi (example on android [here](http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html)). Or your own sockets-based implementation. Whichever you choose though, you will need to spin your own protocol on top of the comms for db querying/synchronisation.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. You should have common server. Save all the data in server. Access it from any physical device

Comment: It is possible, but not often useful.

Comment: sure sure sir? and like apache for PHP is a local server. For android?

Comment: If you want to communicate with 2 devices, you have to use bluetooth, or nfc android beam concept.

Comment: @AlexWilson can you please explain how can we achieve this? thanks